# Persist variable after app reload - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, react-native, momentjs

So I have 5 variables

```
const currentTime = moment().unix()
const eventTime = moment().add(12, 'h').unix()
const diffTime =  eventTime - currentTime
const duration = moment.duration(diffTime * 1000, 'milliseconds')
const interval = 1000
```

and a function that i call inside `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      duration = moment.duration(duration.asMilliseconds() - interval, 'milliseconds')
        let h = moment.duration(duration).hours()
        let m = moment.duration(duration).minutes()
        let s = moment.duration(duration).seconds()
        console.log(h, m, s)
    }, interval)
  }
```

What I need is that after I reload the mobile app the `diffTime` variable will not be defaulted to 12h but it continues to decremet event after app was closed. So when I load the Screen, be there for 30 minutes and then close the app for a 2 hours and come back the `diffTime` will be 9 h 30 min

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: take a look at this library: https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

Answer (score 0):

Use the cache to store the difftime and keep on updating the same like -

```
storage.save({
        key: 'difftimeKey',   // Note: Do not use underscore("_") in key!
        rawData: {
             difftime
        },
        expires: 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30  // ms - 30 days
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 approaches:

- As Karim suggested, you can use a background job...
- You could save that value on the server when you are closing your app and retrieve it when it's loaded back again
- You could save that value and local time on the phone when the app closes. Read it back when you open the app (refresh), compare with actual time and decrease the value on initialization. To save locally, you can take a look at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html